# Measuring TextView in Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

As far as I know, calling `measure(0, 0)` on a `TextView` causes the view to set its measured width and height to a minimum required by current font/text size:

```
public class TextViewSizeTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    public void testTextWidth() {
        TextView view = new TextView(getContext());
        view.setTextSize(42);
        view.setText("test");
        view.measure(0, 0);
        assertEquals(212, view.getMeasuredWidth());
    }
}
```

That magic number 212 is the correct answer - the test passes.

But android unit tests aren't really fast - so I tried to use Robolectric instead.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class TextViewSizeTest {
    @Test
    public void testTextWidth() {
        TextView view = new TextView(Robolectric.application);
        view.setTextSize(42);
        view.setText("test");
        view.measure(0, 0);
        assertThat(view.getMeasuredWidth(), equalTo(212));
    }
}
```

And now this test fails:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: <212>
    but: was <0>
```

So the question is - am I missing something in test setup/initialization or it is a really problem in Robolectric not properly measuring TextView size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right answer is that it is not implemented in Robolectric. Yet. The only relevant function is `Paint`'s `measureText` that returns just text length. It seems I have to extend the Robolectric on my own for this.